# By using ledger nano s, I wanna sign a transaction and send it

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum

I'm trying to send ethereum transaction that sends ERC20 tokens to someone with Ledger Nano S through Node.JS but I'm not able to successfully sign and send this transaction.

First of all, I signed the transaction through the method, signTransaction, of ledgerhq API and then after signing it, I sended it to the main net by using sendSignedTransaction. When I execute below code, Ledger receives request and shows details of a transaction. However, after pressing Ledger's confirm button, the console returns error 'Returned error: Invalid signature: Crypto error (Invalid EC signature)'.

```js
import AppEth from "@ledgerhq/hw-app-eth";
import TransportU2F from "@ledgerhq/hw-transport-u2f";
import TransportNodeHid from "@ledgerhq/hw-transport-node-hid";
import EthereumTx from "ethereumjs-tx"
const Web3 = require('web3');
import { addHexPrefix, bufferToHex, toBuffer } from 'ethereumjs-util';
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));


var destAddresses = ['0xa6acFa18468786473269Dc1521fd4ff40F6481D9'];
var amount = 1000000000000;
var i=0;
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract([token contract ABI... ], '0x74a...');


const data1 = contract.methods.transfer(destAddresses[0], amount).encodeABI();
const exParams = {
  gasLimit: 6e6,
  gasPrice: 3e9,
  from: '0x1A...',
  data : data1,
  to: '0x74a...',
  value: '0x00',
  nonce: "0x0",
  chainId: 1,
  v: "0x01",
  r: "0x00",
  s: "0x00"
}



async function makeSign(txParams) {
  const tx = new EthereumTx(txParams);
  const txHex = tx.serialize().toString("hex");
  const signedTransaction = '0x' + txHex;

  let transport;
  try {
    transport = await TransportNodeHid.create();

    let eth2 = new AppEth(transport);

    const result = await eth2.signTransaction("m/44'/60'/0'/0", txHex).then(result => {
      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + txHex)
      .then(res => {
              console.log(res);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log('sendSignedTransaction');
            console.log(err);
          });
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log('signTransaction');
          console.log(err);
        });

            txParams.r = `0x${result.r, 'hex'}`;
            txParams.s = `0x${result.s, 'hex'}`;
            txParams.v = `0x${result.v, 'hex'}`;

    return result;

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}



makeSign(exParams).then(function () {
  console.log("Promise Resolved2");
}.catch(function () {
  console.log("Promise Rejected2");
});
```

When I only use signTransaction function, I can confirm the transaction in the ledger device and return txhash on the console. However, ultimately I want to broadcast a transaction to the main net. Could you please give me any idea? I want any feedback. Also, if there are any examples of creating and broadcasting a raw transaction by using the ledger, notice me please.

Answer (score 2):

Your code already sends the transaction to the network. However, just awaiting the "send" promise only gives you the transaction hash, not the receipt. You need to treat it as an event emitter and wait for the 'confirmation' event.

```
  const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx.toString('hex'))
    .once('transactionHash', hash => console.log('Tx hash', hash))
    .on('confirmation', (confNumber, receipt) => {
      console.log(`Confirmation #${confNumber}`, receipt);
    })
    .on('error', console.error);
```

To send it to mainnet as you mention, you can either run a local geth node on port 8545 and use your code unchanged, or point web3 at [infura](https://infura.io/) or similar.